# How to create a single-window GUI

Tags: python, pyside2

What is the best way to accomplish a "Single-Window" GUI in PySide2 (or PyQt if that is more familiar), in the same vein as the old school installation wizards?

The two approaches I have thought of would be to:

- Close the present window and create a new window in the same position and size of the last (though I suspect that would seem stutter-y).

OR:

- Create a bunch of widgets and hide/show them as necessary. (Though, I am remembering days of learning Visual Basic and creating awful memory issues doing this).

Is there a better/best practice way of doing this?

Edit: Not really sure why this is getting down-voted. I am asking this question here as I did not see a definitive answer elsewhere. Or are general approach questions disallowed?

Comment: Have you tried to implement your 2 approaches and compare for yourself? generally we hope that the OP (original poster) shows an advance in his research

Comment: read [ask] and review the [tour] and see `QWizard class` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html

Comment: @eyllanesc How do you recommend someone ask general approach questions in the future?

Comment: @eyllanesc it may be sometimes prohibitive to attempt every possible approach and report back, and it is not frowned upon to ask general approach questions. It seems that this user has done some research and is aware of options, yet you indicate that you don't think they asked a good question. I think we may disagree on what an appropriate bar is for research prior to a question.

Comment: @DragonBobZ My comment goes in the sense of improving the question, for me it is not bad but I would have already voted for its closure + downvote. My idea is that not only stay in thoughts and hypotheses but one step more

Comment: @DragonBobZ It's not currently a good question because: (1) it asks about what is "best/better" (so it is primarily opinion-based), and (2) it does not provide a specific context (so it is unclear/too broad). As it stands, pointing out the docs for `QWizard` seems perfectly reasonable, given how vague the requirements are. Anyone asking how to create "wizards" using Qt could have easily found those docs with [a little googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=wizard+Qt) - so I don't see any evidence that the OP has done much real research.